# PHP foreach loop to create JSON from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, loops, for-loop

I have a many to one problem, I have data organized in mysql like:

```
>order1 : mycustomer : item1    
>order1 : mycustomer : item2    
>order2 : mycustomer : item3    
>order2 : mycustomer : item1    
>order3 : mycustomer : item2
```

I want to create the JSON something like (for explanation purposes)

```
>order1 mycustomer    
>> item1    
>> item2,

>order2 mycustomer  
>> item3    
>> item1,    

>order3 mycustomer    
>> item2
```

But my looping is not correct, I am not getting the order with item array then repeat for next order. What am I doing wrong.

```
$query = "SELECT * from `orders` WHERE proc = 'N'";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $onum = $row['order_number'];

    foreach($result as $results)
    {
        $quantity_invoiced = $row[quantity_invoiced];
        $unit_price = $row[unit_price];
        $item_description = $row['item_description'];

        $itemed = $results['item_description'];
        echo $itemed;
      $tx_data[] = [
      "partnerRef" => $onum,
      "lines" => $itemed
      ];
    }


}
$flagupdate = "UPDATE `orders` SET proc = 'Y' where proc = 'N'";
myqueryi_query($conn, $flagupdate);

} else {
echo "no results";
}

echo json_encode($tx_data);
```

Comment: This code is full of issues and errors beyond belief! Did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

There are few syntax errors and also typo mistake in function names.

- Not a proper way to getting indexes from result-set
- `mysqli_query` function name is not correct
- `itemed` is wrapped in double array while not needed for that.

Here is updated code.

```
$query = "SELECT * from `orders` WHERE proc = 'N'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $onum = $row['order_number'];
        $socust = $row['salesorder_cust'];

        foreach($result as $results){
            $quantity_invoiced = $row['quantity_invoiced'];
            $unit_price = $row['unit_price'];
            $item_description = $row['item_description'];
            $itemed = $results['item_description'];
            echo $itemed;

            $tx_data[] = [
            "tpRef" => $socust,
            "partnerRef" => $onum,
            "lines" => $itemed
            ];
        }

    }

    $flagupdate = "UPDATE `orders` SET proc = 'Y' where proc = 'N'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $flagupdate);
} else {
    echo "no results";
}
echo json_encode($tx_data);
```

Comment: Pssst... `echo json_decode($tx_data);` ==> `echo json_encode($tx_data);` :)

Comment: Also note that `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` AND `foreach($result as $results){` - The foreach loop is unnecessary, instead the OP should detect changes between the current `$row['order_number']` and the previous one... And there are even more issues in the code (For example:Overriding `$tx_data` on each iteration)

Comment: I agreed, my answer is to give author of this question a hint that how he can fix syntax and logical errors. definitely my answer may not 100% w.r.t author's expectation

Comment: Alon thanks, how am i overriding tx_data? I wanted to run the loop while I had results for each item that belongs to an order and repeat, I have also fixed the syntax errors in my code.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Thanks for your update that would be the answer but the data is not building the JSON by order number it just created a new line for each item, I tried group by and I couldn't get that to work

Comment: Anyone know how I can build in a hierarchy? With items as a a child of order in a loop

Comment: @hermes please update your question and updated code too. so we can get idea.

Comment: can anyone help

Comment: you need to define sub array. or u may share your code at ping@naveedramzan.com